# Solve autonomous ODE with Mathematica

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematica

I'm given a problem with the ODE

```
y'[x]=y[x]*Sqrt[4-2y[x]]
```

I've tried

```
DSolve[{w'[x] == w[x]*Sqrt[4 - 2*w[x]]}, w[x], x]
```

which gives me

```
{{w[x] -> -2 (-1 + Tanh[1/2 (-2 x - Sqrt[2] C[1])]^2)}}
```

but that doesn't seem correct for some reason.

Can someone please point me in the direction of how to do this problem correctly? I don't really understand Mathematica at all.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't correct?

Comment: Do you have boundary conditions by any chance that you could use to plot the solution? `{{w[x] -> -2 (-1 + Tanh[1/2 (-2 x - Sqrt[2] C[1])]^2)}}` is what I got on Mathematica as well. What were you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

here is a soultion by Maple

$$ x+\frac{1}{2}\,\ln  \left( \sqrt {4-2\,y \left( x \right) }+2 \right)- \frac{1}{2}\,
\ln  \left( -2+\sqrt {4-2\,y \left( x \right) } \right) +{\it \_C1}=0\,.$$

solving the above equation for $y$, gives

$$ y(x) = -{\frac {{{8\rm e}^{2\,x+2\,{\it C1}}}}{ \left( {{\rm e}^{2\,x+2\,
{\it C1}}}-1 \right) ^{2}}}
\,.$$

The differential equation can be solved by the method of separation of variables

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=y \sqrt{4-2y}\implies \int \frac{dy}{y \sqrt{4-2y}}=\int dx + C \,.$$

You need to work out the above integrals and then solve the resulting equation for y to get y as a function of $x$.

Comment: How exactly did you come to this solution?

Comment: @Jay: I'll try to put more details.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: I think I'm close. 

Clear[eq1, eq2, x, y, func]; 
eq1 = Integrate[1/(w*Sqrt[4 - 2*w]), w]; 
eq2 = Integrate[1, x]; 
func = eq1 == eq2; 
Solve[func]; 

gives me 

{{x -> 1/2 Log[2 - Sqrt[4 - 2 w]] - 1/2 Log[2 + Sqrt[4 - 2 w]]}}